# problemas al insertar nuevos datos a excel usando datatables

Tags: c#, excel, datatables

No sé como explicar muy bien mi problema. nunca lo he sabido hacer con certeza.

Empezaré por mostrarles mi código donde le pido al usuario que ingrese los siguientes datos: Nombre,apellido,edad y sexo.
Esos datos se guardaran en Excel.
Tengan en cuenta que el archivo ya tiene datos en él guardados.

mi código es el siguiente:

```
void EscribirEnExcel(string pathfile)
 {

    string nombre="", apellido = "", sexo = "";
    char opt;
    int? Edad = null;
    SLDocument sL = new SLDocument(pathfile);
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sL.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
    int row = stats.EndRowIndex;
    Console.WriteLine(row);

    do {
        Console.WriteLine("Desea añadir más datos? Si(y) No(n) ");
        opt = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        row++;
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'y':

                Console.WriteLine("Escriba su: nombre,apellido,edad y sexo");
            nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            apellido = Console.ReadLine();
            Edad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            sexo = Console.ReadLine();

            dataTable.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Edad", typeof(int));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Sexo", typeof(string));

                //registros
                dataTable.Rows.Add(nombre, apellido, Edad, sexo);
            sL.ImportDataTable(row, 1, dataTable, false);
                sL.Save();

            break;

            case 'n':
                break;

        }
    } while (opt != 'n') ;

 }
```

La segunda vez que trato de introducir datos al  archivo me muestra el siguiente error:
'La columna 'Nombre' ya pertenece a DataTable.' en esta parte del código

```
  dataTable.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
```

Y si quito las columnas, me aparece el  siguiente error:
'La matriz de entrada es más larga que el número de columnas en esta tabla.'
en

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(nombre, apellido, Edad, sexo);
```

¿cómo podría hacerlo de tal manera que puede ingresar los datos sin que me marque ninguno de los errores mencionados?

Answer (score 0):

Las columnas al dataTable solo debes agregar una sola vez, tu código quedaría así:

```
void EscribirEnExcel(string pathfile)
 {
    string nombre="", apellido = "", sexo = "";
    char opt;
    int? Edad = null;
    SLDocument sL = new SLDocument(pathfile);
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sL.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
    int row = stats.EndRowIndex;
    Console.WriteLine(row);
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(string));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Edad", typeof(int));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Sexo", typeof(string));

    do {
        Console.WriteLine("Desea añadir más datos? Si(y) No(n) ");
        opt = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
        row++;
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'y':

                Console.WriteLine("Escriba su: nombre,apellido,edad y sexo");
            nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            apellido = Console.ReadLine();
            Edad = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            sexo = Console.ReadLine();



                //registros
                dataTable.Rows.Add(nombre, apellido, Edad, sexo);
            sL.ImportDataTable(row, 1, dataTable, false);
                sL.Save();

            break;

            case 'n':
                break;

        }
    } while (opt != 'n') ;

 }
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero ahora que lo corrí me salió el siguiente error:
'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
En esta parte del  código
sL.ImportDataTable(row, 1, dataTable, false);